# Save a HTML table to array only working for first 102 elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape [this website](https://sheet2site-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v3/index.php?key=1F7gLiGZP_F4tZgQXgEhsHMqlgqdSds3vO0-4hoL6ROQ&g=1&e=1) and parse the data into an excel sheet.

```
await page.evaluate(() => loadMore());
await page.evaluate(() => loadMore());
await page.evaluate(() => loadMore());
$('tr').each(function(idx) {
    const val = [];
    $('td', this).each(function() {
        val.push($(this).text())
    });
    array.push(val);
});
```

What this code does is first, it clicks the "load more" button 3 times in order to show the entire table. Then, it looks for the elements "tr" and for each of these, it creates an array of the child elements("td") and merges them all together to form a 2D array.

However, my code currently only fetches the data up to the first few elements. It only goes up to the elements until the first "load more" button. In order words, it shows the content up to where it would if I didn't click the "load more " button at all. I suspect that the error is caused by the array being created before the button is clicked because when I use "headless: true" it shows all the elements on the page after clicking the "load more" button 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `loadMore` is not a promise, so you can't `await` until it finish

this is the loadMore function on that page:

```js
function loadMore() {
    //... some code
    
    $.get(url, function (data) { 
         /// HERE is the callback that is called when the async api call returns

            })

    /// more code

}
```

Maybe you can make your own loadMore function adding some promise behavior to wait until it finish.

here i added a promise wrapper to the ajax function and returned that promise

```js
function customLoadMore() {
   //... some code

    let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.get(url, function (data) {

            // same callback code

            resolve() // add a resolve to the promise when the callback finish
        })
    })

    // more code

    return promise; // we return the promise so it can be awaited
}
```

So, now you can `await customLoadMore()`

Comment: Is it also possible if I clicked the "load more" button on the website?

Comment: no, the problem is that you don't have the control of when the `$.get(url,...` returns

Comment: Oh yeah thank you. But there's a lot of other functions on the website. Should I copy those that are referenced in the "load more" one?

Comment: you need to rewrite only the function with async functionality that you want to control